# Access to Excel: Decrease Runtime of Excel VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Similar versions of this question probably have been asked before, but I had questions regarding this issue.

Basically for my function, I just want to run simple a spell check on selected tables from Microsoft Access. Since Access doesn't support individual highlighting all too well in reports, I have the data exported to an Excel file and have VBA run tests for any errors there. After searching online for tips, I have the current code to run faster than what I originally had. But ideally no matter the size of the table I want the function to run under 10 minutes. But currently for some of them, for tables that have 500k+ cells the runtime can still go past 30 minutes. So I was wondering if anything further can be done to better enhance the runtime of this.

```
Private Function Excel_Parser(outFile As String, errorCount As Integer, ByVal tName As String)

 ' EXCEL SETUP VARIABLES
 Dim OpenApp As Excel.Application
 Set OpenApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

 Dim parserBook As Excel.Workbook
 Dim parserSheet As Excel.Worksheet

 ' Opening exported file
 Set parserBook = OpenApp.Workbooks.Open(outFile, , , , , , , , , , , , , , XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile)

 If parserBook Is Nothing Then
    status2 = "Failed to set Workbook"
    Exit Function
 Else

     status3 = "Searching [" & tName & "] for errors"

     Set parserSheet = parserBook.Worksheets(1)

     ' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ' Fetch Table information
     lastCellAddress = parserSheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address

     Dim rng As Range
     Set rng = parserSheet.Range("A1:" & lastCellAddress)
     ' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     ' Populating entire table data from Excel into array to save runtime.
     Dim dataArr() As Variant, R As Long, C As Long
     dataArr = rng.Value2

     ' Parsing through table data array
     nRows = UBound(dataArr, 1)
     nCols = UBound(dataArr, 2)

     fileOuterLoop1 = Time

     For R = 1 To nRows

         For C = 1 To nCols

             cCell = CStr(dataArr(R, C))
             status4 = "Now running check on cell: [" & cCell & "]"

             If cCell <> "" Or Not (IsNull(cCell)) Then

                If Not OpenApp.Application.CheckSpelling(cCell) Then

                    errorCount = errorCount + 1

                    ' Change cell status
                    vArr = Split(parserSheet.Cells(1, C).Address(True, False), "$")
                    fCol = vArr(0)
                    xDef = fCol & R
                    parserSheet.Range(xDef).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 213, 124)

                End If

             End If  'End of cCell is null check
         Next C
     Next R

     fileOuterLoop2 = Time
     fCheck = Format(fileOuterLoop2 - fileOuterLoop1, "hh:mm:ss")

     ' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     parserSheet.Columns.AutoFit
     status7 = "Loop Finished. Runtime: " & fCheck

     ' Save and Cleanup
     OpenApp.DisplayAlerts = False
     parserBook.SaveAs FileName:=outFile, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
     parserBook.Saved = True
     parserBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
     OpenApp.DisplayAlerts = True

     Set parserSheet = Nothing
     Set parserBook = Nothing
     Set OpenApp = Nothing

     ' Return errorCount for database
     Excel_Parser = errorCount

 End If

End Function
```

outFile is a PATH string, where file exists from a TransferSpreadsheet command. And "status" variables are just error log textboxes in the Access form. I have tried adding in both Access' and Excel's versions of ScreenUpdating or Echo but I found that these commands actually make my function runtime slightly slower.

Comment: Is there any need to split by space?  You can say `Application.CheckSpelling("test thes out")` which gives false, and `Application.CheckSpelling("test this out")` is true for example

Comment: just curious. how are you correcting the spelling mistakes after finding the errors? I think you should probably do this in Access where it gives you an option to correct?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Oh you're right. I believe that while writing the code there were some errors from a previous version which didn't line up with the Excel's default spell check program, so I added it by individual word to be sure. But even still, removing all the extra arrays still doesn't make much of a difference in runtime as it only saves ~1min.

Comment: @krishKM I'm not. The function is to only detect errors and highlight the cells in the spreadsheet. I looked at Access' function, but in terms of VBA I can't seem to find a command where it doesn't prompt the user for the menu at every single word.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Do you use `status4` somewhere in your code to show current state of work and just omitted it here in the sample? If so, think about not displaying it for every loop, but maybe only every 50 steps by using `Mod` operator.

   See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mod-operator
2. You should avoid screen refreshs and more on every loop in Excel by setting this before the loop:

   ```
   OpenApp.ScreenUpdating = False
   OpenApp.EnableEvents = False
   OpenApp.Calculation = Excel_XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual
   ```

   And this after the loop:

   ```
   OpenApp.ScreenUpdating = True
   OpenApp.EnableEvents = True
   OpenApp.Calculation = Excel_XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic
   ```

It can end in a massive speed up. Give it a try.

Comment: 1) Pretty much. It displays the current cell that's being processed for debugging purposes only. It will be removed in the final code for the form that enables up to 5 table selection. 2) I have tried that before in the past, along with Access' Echo version, where I have experienced a slightly slower runtime as mentioned before. When I adding the suggestion bit in, now the function prompts the user with the "File X is now available for Write-Editing" menu, which I don't want. Thanks anyway.